# How can I use my JSON without triggering a new API request everytime I want to use my data?

Tags: angularjs, rest, http, ngresource

I'm wanting to to have my app limit its requests to the server without saving the data. Is there a way I can do this without making a request to the server every time my http request is invoked? What are some of the different methods this can be done and best practices/trade offs for each?

Comment: Are you talking about getting JSON from the server and then reuse this without calling the server every time?

Comment: @sjokkogutten yes I am. I know caching is a method but I'm wonder more big picture and how angular handles the requests. For instance if a service makes the request for a resource that's loaded into a controller is that service making a http request every time the controllers called? If so that could make a lot of  unnecessary requests

Comment: You don't say what the backend system is, nor the client. I believe that makes a difference.  With a Meteor.js backend for example, you get n way data binding (if coded correctly) whilst still using angular or react on the front end.  If the client is mobile, it makes sense to use local storage because connectivity can be intermittent.

Comment: I'm using angulars resource inside of an ionic mobile app  wrapped inside of a service and I don't have back and privileges but requests do you return an etag so I have angularis HTTP ngresources and restangular. I've heard contradictory things on in Ngresource supporting it and I know resti angular out of the box

Answer (score 2):

That would depend on you needs. One approach would be to store the results in a request in a factory and retrieve those.

```
app.factory('DataService', function($http) {
  var values;
  var requestValues = function() {
    $http.get("/api/getValues").then(
        function(results){
            values = results;
        });
  };
  var getValues = function() {
    return values;
  };
  return {
    requestValues : requestValues, // this will make a http request and store the result
    getValues: getValues // this will call the stored result (without making a http request)
  }
});
```

And then in you controller call the functions to make a request for the values and then get the values. There are two functions, `requestValues()` to make the http request and save the result and `getValues()` to get the stored values without making a http request. Once `requestValues()` has been called, you should be able to call `getValues()` from anywhere to get the values without making a new http request.

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope, DataService) {
  var init = function (){
    DataService.requestValues(); // this will make the http request and store the result
    $scope.items = DataService.getValues(); // this will get the result
  };

  var justGetValues = function(){
    $scope.items = DataService.getValues(); // this will get the result (without making a http request)
  };

});
```

Now you simply have to call `DataService.getUpdates();` whenever you need the values. (You might want to wrap these in a `promise`. I have refrained from doing this due to simplicity)


Alternatively you could use the cache option as mentioned by @JLRishe. Angular's $http has a cache built in, so simply set cache to true in its options

```
$http.get(url, { cache: true})
  .success(){ 
   // on success 
 }.error(){ 
  // on error
};
```

Comment: First off thank you for taking the time to answer my question, currently I have a pretty similar setup but I'm using angulars service `service` as apposed to a factory and I print the result to my console (this is inside my service function) and its being logged everytime the controller that has the service injected in is being called (understandably) ergo it's making an http request everytime every view that is associated with the controller and the service is called. So i was wondering if you knew —without caching— is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Ok. Whether you are using a service or factory should not make a difference. I have edited my answer in an attempt to make it more clear how you could use the stored result to avoid making unnecessary http calls

Comment: That is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cache` option in the `config` argument to the various `$http` methods:

```
$http.get('/someUrl', {
    cache: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way is simply to have a JavaScript integer variable that counts how many requests have been made to the server, and when a defined maximum limit is reached, to stop making requests to the server.

Without knowing more about *why* you want to do it, it is difficult to be more specific.