# Angular - initializing modal($uibModal's ) data only once

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-controller

I am using angular-bootstrap `modal`, by [documation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).
Unlike the example I am loading data from `$http` request and I want the `data` to load only once, using `ng-init` loads the data each time the modal is open.
Here is my `modal controller`, `serevlet` is the name of the `service` I use to send `$http` requests.

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, serevlet) {
  //the data I want to init
  $scope.data = null;

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };

  $scope.sendGet = function(){
   serevlet.sendGet().then(function(data){
       $scope.data = data;
    };
  }

});
```

I hope it is clear what I want to do, if there is a way using `.run` or `.config` to do it?

Comment: Cache the response in `serevlet.sendGet()`, check cache before ajax, and after ajax cache it to some var, then do resolve.

Comment: And if I dont want to use cache mechanism, is there other way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968655/how-can-i-use-my-json-without-triggering-a-new-api-request-everytime-i-want-to-u/33969521#33969521

Comment: Thanks, works for me.